# Track form conversions confirmation page URL is the same as the form

Tags: forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track form completions on a page where the form's URL is the same as the confirmation page.

[Form Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL2oc.jpg)

Does anybody know if this can be done with Google Tag Manager/Google Analytics please?

[Completion page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjMwT.jpg)

Simply tracking clicks of the Submit button will result in false positives because sometimes people will not type the security code correctly.

Is there a tracking code of some sort that can be added to the confirmation page, so that each time it loads the count goes up one?

I'm grateful of any help you can provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in visibility trigger - e.g. as soon as a link element with the link back to the homepage becomes visible you let the trigger fire. Specifics depend on the CSS id or class for that link (if any, else you'd have to test the click text).

In the visibility trigger you might have to enable "listen for DOM changes" if the confirmation message is loaded per Ajax (as opposed to just have their CSS display property set to 'none'.

Comment: Thanks Eike. Appreciate your assistance. Do you know how this would work if it's a button rather than click text please?